# Automatical translation in desktop application

Tags: java, chat, translation

I run a chat service where people of all nationalities are welcome. The problem is that they can't communicate. I don't have enough users to create different chat rooms for each language.

I'd like to provide an automatical real-time translation integrated in the chat, which is programmed in plain Java.

I don't want to hack google translate or do something like that.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no options unless paying a lot of money for this service.

Answer (score -1):

There is a Java client API for Google Translate (but it is an unofficial one). You can find it at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-translate-java/

Comment: but that's hacking google, and i'm distributing my android app using their service